# Set a requesting port for HTTP WebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I need to set the port of a HttpRequest. This is the port the Request is coming FROM.

Normal HTTP scenario:

Request: 127.0.0.1:6745 --> www.stackoverflow.com
Response: 1227.0.0.1:6745 <-- www.stackoverflow.com

Request: 127.0.0.1:8096 --> www.stackoverflow.com
Response: 1227.0.0.1:8096 <-- www.stackoverflow.com

My scenario:

Request: 127.0.0.1:6745 --> www.stackoverflow.com
Response: 1227.0.0.1:6745 <-- www.stackoverflow.com

Request: 127.0.0.1:6745 --> www.stackoverflow.com
Response: 1227.0.0.1:6745 <-- www.stackoverflow.com

The request must always come from a defined port. Is this even possible in the HTTP protocol? If yes, how do I use the WebRequest class in the .NEt framework? Or do I have to use manual sockets?

Comment: TCP/IP has never worked like you want it to. It would be stupid if it did.

Comment: It was not my idea, a third party wants our ip address and port number in order to allow us to consume their HTTP XML service.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by requesting port? If it is the temporary port assigned by the OS I don't think that you have any control over it with [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx). IMHO it would be better to leave this management to the operating system or you could run into some conflicts with other applications.

Comment: Ok. How about just findout out what port was used by WebRequest? Is there a way to determine this after the request is made?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to a `WebClient` instead of `HttpWebRequest` since it should keep the connection alive for a period of time.

Do note that HTTP was not built to keep connections open. The connection will always be closed after a a period of idle time.